# IHS vs Apache in Websphere Application issues

Tags: apache, websphere, httpserver

We had configured our WCS with Apache server but the requirement was to use IHS server instead of Apache. We configured the same and there were no problems on the same.

When there is a specific external URL to which our site needs to be redirected, we get the below error

```
SSL0266E: Handshake Failed, Could not establish SSL proxy connection.
```

We had been spending days on this now and we do not have directions to proceed. Any pointers to proceed on the same will be helpful

Comment: Did you configure IHS to trust the issuer of the backend servers certificate?  Did you look at a packet capture to see what transpired during the handshake?   What version/release are you using? What protocols/cipherd do both sides support?  Presumably you are paying for support -- have you tried using it?

Comment: hi@covener, thats where need pointers in getting the certificates migrated from apache to IHS

Comment: Your certificate needs to be included in the SSL keystore using iKeyman.  Search for it, IBM provides procedures to include OpenSSL certificates in iKeyman.